# Shared Component with routerLink @Input()

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components

I want to create a shared component, that has a button, and when clicked, routes the user somewhere.  The route should come from the consumer of the component.  How can I achieve this?

---

I'm thinking I want to make the route an `@Input()` parameter.  Is that a good approach?

**Shared Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: '<button [how do I bind the router parameters?]>Go Somewhere</button>'
})
```

**In Some Other Module**

```
<some-component [routerLink]="['blah', someDynamicValue]">
</some-component>

<some-component 
  [routerLink]="['blah-2', someDynamicValue2]" 
  [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" 
  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
</some-component>
```

---

Surely, someone has already asked this before?  I can't seem to track it down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `@Input()` is a good aproach

Try this

**Shared Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `<button [routerLink]="componentLink" 
     [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" 
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Go Somewhere</button>`
})
export class SomeComponent{

  @Input()
  componentLink: any[];

  //Initialize it as an empty array for default values
  @Input()
  componentLinkActive: string[] = [];

  //Same goes here
  @Input()
  componentLinkActiveOptions: {exact: boolean} = { exact: false }

}
```

**In Some Other Module**

```
<some-component 
[componentLink]="['blah', someDynamicValue]" 
[componentLinkActive]="['is-active']" 
[componentLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"></some-component>
```

And also in your shared component module make sure to import the `RouterModule`

Comment: Thanks John!  I've update my question for different usages of `SomeComponent`.  How do I add `routerLinkActive` and `routerLinkActiveOptions` as optional input parameters?

Comment: @spottedmahn just updated my answer, I hope it helps you

Comment: Critical part of this solution is to ensure that `componentLink` in `<some-component [componentLink] ... >` is wrapped with square brackets. Otherwise Angular's parameter parsing logic won't run and the parameter value will be a plain string (not an array).